# How to stop other users seeing files uploaded to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-iam

I have an Amazon S3 Bucket with one folder within it. My requirement is for many IAM users to upload files to that folder via the Management Console. However, users must not able to see/download the files uploaded by other IAM users.

Creating a different folder and writing an IAM policy to access the bucket and prefixing the folder name is fine, but we don't want that as we have have about 100 users that will be uploading the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bucket policies + IAM policies is the only way to go.

S3 objects do not have user-associations built in (like other local filesystems to, like NTFS or ext3/4).

So the only way to differentiate one user's files from another, is to put an ID in the object's key or by (maybe) an S3 object's tags.

But you cannot escape using bucket policies. You can avoid writing many policies by making smart use of bucket policy variables like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Source: [IAM Policy Variables Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

By using the `$(aws:username}` variable, you can have this one policy apply to all users. Just have them put their own files in a folder with their own username in the name.